# How to run javascript/html page

Tags: html, javascript

I want to know what is the terminal command for compiling and executing Javascript/HTML.
Is it the same as that of compilation of C program or is it different?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Unless you have some special situation, there's no command for that, since Javascript (and HTML) is sent to the browser in source form.

Comment: For javascript and html to be executed on your system you need a webserverr. Have a look at `apache`.

Comment: Rinzwind: no, you don't. You need a server for a server language (like PHP) not for a client language (like Javascript/HTML). You just need a web browser for that, double click on the file and voila, file opened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) is a [markup language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) which is interpreted by a [web browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser). There is no such thing as compiling HTML.

[JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) is a [dynamic programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_language) that is executed at runtime by a [JavaScript engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine). That means JavaScript is not compiled.

As you're mentioning both JavaScript and HTML, read this : [JavaScript use in web pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_JavaScript#Use_in_web_pages).

> The primary use of JavaScript is to write functions that are embedded in or included from HTML pages and that interact with the Document Object Model (DOM) of the page.

I don't really understand what you're trying to do but assuming you've got some .js and .html files, just open the html ones with your browser, like this:

```
firefox your_stuff.html
```

Comment: There is "such a thing" as in Windows CHM files... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help

Comment: Christopher, I really doubt he was asking about that and I really think the answer above is a good one.

Comment: @mrpotato Hee-hee! No doubt... I know. Thanks. It was for Maxime to do know that there really is "such a thing" (even though it does not apply to this).

Comment: Haha! I would never have thought of chm files ^^ However i suspect them to be more a compressed _compilation_ of html files rather than compiled html. Also CHM is sometimes referenced as standing for _compressed HTML Help metafile_, see the french version of the link you gave us or test `wget /dev/null http://www.innovasys.com/products/ce/examples/realworld.zip;7z e -y realworld.zip;7z e -so RealWorld.chm default.html|more`. As for javascript, i'm aware you can do weird thing like compiling it to java, like with [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino_JavaScript_Compiler) :)